# Execute a php function tas background process hrough url using curl command

Tags: php, curl

I have function for converting files and I want to run it as background process cuing curl.

```
        $url = sendMessages.php;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $curled=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

I used above code but didn't work.please advice?
Do I have to use full path url?

Answer (score 0):

yes the url is expected to be a full url, that may look something like

```
$url = 'http://localhost/file/convertfiles.php';
```

the actual url really depends of your setup,

also you would probably be confronted to timeout issues, these can be overcome but I don't know enough about what you are trying to do or your setup to tell you how

Comment: but the curl doesn't run as background process, how to proceed?